# Solana Metaplex Candy Machine `tokenMint` metadata is null

Tags: nft, solana, metaplex

I ended up creating a candy machine instance following the guide here https://hackmd.io/@levicook/HJcDneEWF

I'm running into an issue now where, when I call the `mintOneToken` from the GUI code

```js
await mintOneToken(candyMachineAccount, wallet.publicKey)
```

found [here](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex/blob/92eb2fb7bcd524cab5a6ec51dd8049cf034477b3/js/packages/fair-launch/src/candy-machine.ts#L201), I get an error because the CandyMachineAccount object's `state.tokenMint` field is null, but we see [here](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex/blob/92eb2fb7bcd524cab5a6ec51dd8049cf034477b3/js/packages/fair-launch/src/candy-machine.ts#L212) that it needs to not be null.

```js
const userPayingAccountAddress = (
    await getAtaForMint(candyMachine.state.tokenMint, payer)
)[0];
```

Interestingly, when I load other candy machine instances which are not my own, I see that their `tokenMint` field is non-null, so I'm assuming there's some command I need to run or contract call I need to make to set this field to be non-null for my candy machine instance on-chain. How can I properly set the `tokenMint` field?

For reference, here's a candy machine ID on Mainnet-Beta which has a non-null `tokenMint`

EodXoBBFMWMXe3KKpwAFRa3BHDDWF3y7S8DcGRUTdG9U

```json
{
    "authority": {
        "_bn": "c474397eca84550ae504367dd7dbac1a292322eadc7cae7b67e7d60d7c9b99ce"
    },
    "wallet": {
        "_bn": "bfcac40c32edd90f5616a3b1b4e8e15312ba42a1d10966b1045d404c2e071996"
    },
    "tokenMint": {
        "_bn": "3af36dc3408953a0cf7c68de1fe61539f3d2144f4e229efa98cb3d1bc1235791"
    },
    "config": {
        "_bn": "7525d86480fd7940b0e76fdbdd7fc7ce60216b94e1c1909ad81166f75c422e5d"
    },
    "data": {
        "uuid": "8tJAvu",
        "price": "01",
        "itemsAvailable": "1d",
        "goLiveDate": "6148b5dc"
    },
    "itemsRedeemed": "00",
    "bump": 253
}
```

And then here's mine on DevNet

3K7iVL5tE2D7F8gu6hXZMp9p2WJUPqQMZnxQn2aQ622p

```json
{
    "authority": {
        "_bn": "7297dc02b1a174a34d635d952df3621a44eba1c747a7fe79965eb00cab3cfa83"
    },
    "wallet": {
        "_bn": "7297dc02b1a174a34d635d952df3621a44eba1c747a7fe79965eb00cab3cfa83"
    },
    "tokenMint": null,
    "config": {
        "_bn": "506ae5975d15bad548e7976891ca30621e155cb3b95a8671736bea6715e2887e"
    },
    "data": {
        "uuid": "6QvA3Y",
        "price": "3b9aca00",
        "itemsAvailable": "0b",
        "goLiveDate": "614e2030"
    },
    "itemsRedeemed": "01",
    "bump": 255
}
```

Comment: this guide is pretty old tbh which version of CM are you using